# How to require a unique login link?

Tags: php

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to be able to show a homepage of a site. However, all this homepage does is allow you to enter an email address. It then sends an email to you, containing a unique link to get past the homepage to the actual content. It wouldn't require any actual accounts or logins, just the possession of the uniquely emailed link. (It will also only send to .edu addresses).

What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an SQL table mapping usernames to key codes.
2. When the homepage form is submitted, generate a random 16 letter string of A-Z, a-z, 0-9 characters.
3. Insert an SQL row into the table mapping the username to the 16 letter string (use PDO).
4. E-mail the user a link like example.org/login/email@email.com/rAnDomStRiNgHeRe
5. Setup .htaccess with ModRewrite to map example.org/login/([^/])+/([A-Za-z0-9])+ to example.org/verify-login.php?email=$1&code=$2
6. Create verify-login.php, which uses PDO to query the database for any entries in the table with the mapping of the given email to the given code.
7. If there is a match, take the user to the actual content.
8. If you need to protect the content, store a cookie with the e-mail and key, and then perform a database lookup making sure the cookie e-mail and cookie key map to each other in the database.  This check must be made on every singe page that is to be protected.

As a side note, it probably would be best to base64_encode the email:key and use that in the URL.  Update .htaccess accordingly.  Then, in verify-login.php, decode the base64 string, split it up into email and key, and perform your check.

Comment: If you hash the e-mail, there isn't much security.  What if the OP wants to have the signup page only last for a month, after which, no one else can use it?  If you just hashed the e-mail, people could generate their own hashes and get in months later.

Comment: Yeah, didn't think about it too hard. I deleted the comment.